# RMySQL - automating reading data from DB tables

Tags: mysql, r, rmysql

I have a piece of code thus:

```
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "****", password = "****", dbname = "c_global", host = "")

df_ipt_rate_history   <- fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from ipt_rate_history"), n=-1)
df_map_occupation     <- fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from map_occupation"), n=-1)
df_map_titles         <- fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from map_titles"), n=-1)
df_pcode_full_areas   <- fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from pcode_full_areas"), n=-1)
df_pcode_rics_regions <- fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from pcode_rics_regions"), n=-1)
df_pcode_sector_areas <- fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, "select * from pcode_sector_areas"), n=-1)
```

...and so on (multiple tables)

```
dbDisconnect(mydb)
```

It works fine but is there a way to set up some kind of loop that reads every table in a DB (and outputs to a data frame) in a single command?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `dbListTables` to list all your tables within your database, and then read all their lines and columns using the utility function `dbReadTable`.

```
all_data <- lapply(dbListTables(mydb), dbReadTable, conn = mydb)
```

Btw, unless it is necessary, it is maybe not a good idea to load in memory all the data if it can be read from a database when needed.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming each table is in a different structure, one option would be to use `lapply` or `purrr::map` to fetch each dataframe and store them in a list.

In base R:

```r
mydb <- dbConnect(MySQL(), user = "****", password = "****", dbname = "c_global", host = "")

table_names <- c("ipt_rate_history",
                 "map_titles",
                 "pcode_full_areas",
                 "pcode_rics_regions",
                 "pcode_sector_areas")

df <- lapply(table_names, 
             function(x) fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, paste("select * from", x), n = -1)))

df <- setNames(df, table_names)
```

With `purrr` package:

```r
table_names <- c("ipt_rate_history",
                 "map_titles",
                 "pcode_full_areas",
                 "pcode_rics_regions",
                 "pcode_sector_areas")

df <- purrr::map(table_names, 
                 ~fetch(dbSendQuery(mydb, paste("select * from", .), n = -1)))

df <- purrr::set_names(df, table_names)
```

Then you can access each table with `df$table_name`, *e.g.* `df$ipt_rate_history`.